# How do I multiply two columns together using SQLite Database in Android?

Tags: java, android

I created a table using the SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(
                "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_SWIMMERLAPS + " INT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_SPONSOR + " DEC NOT NULL );"

                );
```

How would I  multiply the values of the swimmer laps by the sponsor using an SQLiteDatbase method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + KEY_SWIMMERLAPS + " * " + KEY_SPONSOR + " AS result FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
    Log.w("result", cursor.getDouble(0)+"");
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. but how would I return the result from this query? The code I have so far looks like this: http://pastebin.com/yXjY3V2G

Comment: @Sheldon KEY_NAME is not in your query

Comment: Take a look here: http://pastebin.com/6P9rLLD4. I've added the KEY_NAME in the query.